# Sql query to combine two column values of diff ProductCode and with same Productname

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following table

```
 ID   PCode   Pname
 ----------------------------------    
  1     A1    Book
  2     A2    Oxford Dictionary
  3     A3    Book
```

Expected output:

```
  ID  PCode  Pname
  ---------------------------------------
  1     A1   Book_A1
  2     A2   Oxford Dictionary
  3     A3   Book_A3
```

If `Pname` is same for different `Pcode` then result need to be `Pname_Pcode` like `Book_A1` and `Book_A3`.

Please give the solution which will helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table again with the condition to take only the records `having` duplicates. Then check this condition in a `case`

```
select t1.id, t1.pcode, case when t2.pname is not null 
                             then t2.pname + '_' + t1.pcode
                             else t1.pname
                        end as pname
from your_table t1
left join
(
  select pname 
  from your_table
  group by pname
  having count(*) > 1
) t2 on t1.pname = t2.pname
```